# Why does the series of a rapidly Cauchy sequence in $L^p$ converge in $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$From Royden:

> For $E$ a measurable subset of finite measure in $\Bbb R$, and $1\lt p\lt\infty$, let $\{f_n\}\subset\mathcal{L}^p(E)$ be a rapidly Cauchy sequence with limit $f\in\mathcal{L}^p(E)$. By completeness of $\mathcal{L}^q(E)$, the function: $$g=\sum_{k=1}^\infty|f_k|$$Belongs to $\mathcal{L}^p(E)$.

Here $q$ denotes the conjugate of $p$ - although how this is relevant I have no idea - $\frac{p}{p-1}$, and Royden's meaning of rapidly Cauchy is:

> A sequence $f_n$ is rapidly Cauchy in a normed linear space if there exists a sequence $\epsilon_k$ of positive reals such that $\|f_{k+1}-f_k\|\lt\epsilon^2_k$ for all $k$, and $\sum_{k\ge1}\epsilon_k\lt\infty$

The corollaries of this are that, returning to the problem at hand:

$$\|f_{n+k}-f_k\|_p\lt\sum_{m=k}^\infty\epsilon^2_k\lt\infty,\quad\forall n$$

And the latter sum may become as small as desired.

We also have that:

$$\left(\int_E|f_n|^p\,\d\mu\right)^{1/p}\lt\left(\int_E|f_k|^p\,\d\mu\right)^{1/p}+\sum_{m=k}^\infty\epsilon^2_k\quad\forall n\gt k$$

This says little about the series of $g$ however - in fact it is not necessary that $\|f_k\|_p$ tends to zero as $k\to\infty$.

I believe Royden made here a mistake, and they really mean to write $g=\sum_{k\ge1}|f_k-f|$, which I believe *would* be convergent in $\mathcal{L}^p$, although it is not straightaway obvious that even this is true. Is this right?

The only wrinkle here is that $E$ is of finite measure. However, this still doesn't imply that we have convergence of $g$ as far as I can't tell.

Comment: $f_k=f_1$ for all $k$ is a  counter-example. I think it is just a typo in the book.

Comment: The desired theorem he intended to prove was: "Suppose $\varphi$ is a continuous convex function on $\Bbb R$ satisfying $|\varphi(x)|\le c_1+c_2\cdot|x|^p$ for all $x$ and some fixed constants $c_1,c_2$. Then there is an $f_0\in\mathcal{L}^p(E)$ which minimises $\int_E\varphi\circ f_0\,\d\mu$". Is the theorem itself even correct, do you know @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: He was going to use this $g$ and employ dominated convergence, but since $E$ is of finite measure I think we can just take $f+\epsilon$ for an arbitrary $\epsilon$ and one would get domination